# Web app link to open an installed app on Android Device

Tags: android, hyperlink, web

Has anyone get any ideas how I could open an installed app on a device from a link inside a web app. I am planning on building a web app for Android 3.0 tablet device that would have a quiz on it. The quiz would require a user to scan in QR Codes using an installed app on the device so essentially what I need to do is have a link saying scan QR Code that would open the QR Code app. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "QR Code" app in question is Barcode Scanner, [they have instructions for how to set up links](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages).

If the "QR Code" app in question is your own, you will need to set up an `<intent-filter>` for your activity that is similar to the one Barcode Scanner uses:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="zxing.appspot.com" android:path="/scan"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

You would replace the host with some domain that you control. Ideally, you put a Web page at the URL indicated by the host and path, so that if somebody clicks the link in the Web app and they do not have the "QR Code" app installed, you show them a page that explains what they are missing.

Comment: I am looking to do similar to being asked.  How can i receive data from website to app?