# open media link from php page I to android app

Tags: android, browser, hyperlink, video-streaming, mobile-application

I have a web site that is responsive and works great on tablet and mobile devices, and I want to allow users on my site to open our media links in an app. The links are to streaming media .m3u8 files.

I am looking for a way to take a normal href link and when the user clicks on it in their mobile browser, Android asks what app they would like to open it in. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web app link to open an installed app on Android Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723429/web-app-link-to-open-an-installed-app-on-android-device)

Comment: sorry your wrong read next time ! this link is for a web app more than likley using webview packed as an apk

Comment: mines is a website not an apk or web app the site has no connections to android or the android apis